# Set of conjugate vectors that span both Krylov space

Tags: linear-algebra

If $P$ contains a set of conjugate vectors that span Krylov space of matrix $A$, i.e. $\mathcal{K}(A, x)$, and also $P$ span Krylov space of matrix $\mathcal{K}(B, x)$, is it true that the diagonal matrix:

$$
P^T A P = P^T B P = D
$$

And is there a proof for this?

**EDIT**: Pardon for the lack of clarity, here is my situation. I have a quadratic optimisation $\dfrac{1}{2}x^T A x + b^T x$. Applying conjugate gradient method to find the minimum gives me a set of search direction $P$. Hence from conjugacy we should have:

$$
P^T A P = D
$$

where D is a diagonal matrix. Now if my matrix $A = B+C$, can I draw the same conclusion where

$$
P^T B P = D
$$

is this legit?

Comment: You need to be much more specific here. You have the range of $P$ containing the two Krylov subspaces, but that gives us considerable freedom. You need to narrow it down.

Comment: hm... maybe let's say we can focus on the case where $A = B + C$ where $C$ is some other matrix? I don't know what kind of restrictions you would want tbh...

Comment: Suppose $P$ was generated by applying the Arnoldi algorithm to the pair $(A,b)$, then the best you could hope for is to have $P^TAP$ tridiagonal. In general, you would have $P^TAP$ upper Hessenberg, and you would need $A$ symmetric to have $P^TAP$ tridiagonal. Moreover, there is more than one way to define conjugate vectors. I recommend that you edit your question and include more information about your exact situation.

Comment: Have just editted the question with more context. Thanks.

Comment: There is no harm in doing an experiment. I suspect that you will find that the answer is no. The vectors generated by the CG algorithm depend very much on the matrix in question. You can not expect them to perform nicely with respect to what appears to be an arbitrary splitting of A into a sum $A = B+C$.

Comment: My argument being if $P$ is the search direction for $A$, then $P$ spans the Krylov subspace $\mathcal{K}(A, x) = span[x, Ax, A^2 x....]$. Since $A = B + C$, this means that $\mathcal{K}(A,x) = \mathcal{K}(B+C, x) = span[x, Bx, B^2x... + (C)]$. This makes $P$ also spans the subspac $\mathcal{K}(B,x)$, and hence should the vectors in the set be conjugate?

Comment: When you write $K(B+C,x) = \text{span}\{x, Bx, B^2x, \dotsc (C) \}$, then what does the last term really mean? If $Cx=0$, then I understand why,
$K(B+C,x) = \text{span}\{x, Bx, B^2x \dotsc \}$.